# generate java classes from xsd with mutlitlevel imports

Tags: java, maven, xsd, jaxb

I am trying to generate java classes from xsd using JAXB plugin but not able to get the effect as I want. 
My use case is :

a.xsd has some elements.
b.xsd has some elements.

composite.xsd needs to have some elements from "a.xsd" and "b.xsd" as well as it's own elements.

I have tried many options so far. I can import the xsds ( a and b ) into "composite" but that would only enable me to use the elements from "a" and "b" into "composite" xsd but when I generate the classes using jaxb, it won't automatically bring all contents from "a and b". 
For example :

```
a.xsd -> has "name" element.
b.xsd -> has "phone" element.
composite.xsd -> imports a and b and has "nickname" element.
```

So if I don't explicitly use "name" and "phone" in composite.xsd, generated java class won't generate those. Also there could be multilevel imports ( kind of inheritance like composite.xsd includes "b.xsd" and "b.xsd" includes "a.xsd ).

So I want composite to have all elements from "a" and "b" in generated class without explicitly repeating a.xsd and b.xsd's elements in composite.xsd.

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
composite.class
name, phone, nickname.
```

Please advise.

Here are some more details with xsd details:
( field names are different that what I put in the original question but will give a gist of it. ).

```
**a.xsd**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:complexType name="Customer">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" />
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>

**b.xsd**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:complexType name="Payments">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="amount" type="xsd:float" />
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>


**composite.xsd**
```

```
<xsd:include schemaLocation="x.xsd" />
<xsd:include schemaLocation="y.xsd" />

<xsd:complexType name="CustomerPayments">
<xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element name="customer" type="Customer" />
  <xsd:element name="payments" type="Payments" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

WITH above xsds, what I want to achieve is to have a composite java class (generated by JAXB maven plugin ) to automatically have fields like "name" and "amount" from imported/included xsds.

Comment: Post your XSD's, and what have you tried so far.. That would be helpful to resolve the issue

Comment: sure, just added sample xsd snippets.

Answer (score 0):

The generated `CustomerPayments` class will not contain properties`name` or `amount`, this is not how XJC works.

But it will contain field `customer` and `payments` of types `Customer` and `Payments` which will contain properties `name` and `amount` respectively. So you can do `customerPayments.getCustomer().getName()` at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Lexicore. Appreciate it. Looks like I have to think of some other options then, somehow my use case requires importing/inheriting all fields from parent xsd to child xsd ... ( generated java classes ).

Comment: @Sacs Why do you need all the fields in one class?

Comment: basically we have bunch of projects, some of them use xsd to generate pojos and some don't use but the ones that don't use have created java classes (POJO) manually with lot of repetition of fields which already exists in the older project which uses xsd generated pojos. To start streamlining these with minimal impact as a first step, I am trying to use xsds all over to generate pojos to avoid manual generation of pojos. To achieve these, I was thinking of having xsd inheritance ( kind of ), to have all fields from the other xsd which already exist and add anything specific on top of it.

Comment: @Sacs XSD "inheritance" as you call it has nothing to do with "all the fields in one class". If you have schema includes and imports, type extension or resriction, all of this works with JAXB/XJC. Trying to put all the fields in one class does not because it does not make sense. Schemas allow complex structures, you can't represent those by putting all the fields in one class. You are solving the wrong problem.